# Как подключить библиотеку PDFSharp ?

Tags: c#, библиотеки

До этого работал с `iTextSharp` (скачал `dll`, подключил - всё), но сейчас пришлось поработать с этой. `DLL` не нашёл, везде раздаются только исходники.
Вопрос: как её подключить?

Answer (score 3):

Используя Nuget.

В студии: Сервис - Диспетчер пакетов библиотек - Консоль диспетчера пакетов.

В консоли: `Install-Package PdfSharp`